# Android: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry after software upload on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, exception, workbench

Does anyone have this problem before?

```
!SESSION 2013-09-26 11:34:22.897 -----------------------------------------------
```

> eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200 java.version=1.7.0_05
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_NZ Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product Command-line arguments:  -os win32
>   -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-26 11:34:32.148 !MESSAGE One or
>   more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints
>   are not resolved: !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-26
>   11:34:32.148 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core_1.1.202.v201208171701.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core 2 0 2013-09-26
>   11:34:32.148 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi
>   2 0 2013-09-26 11:34:32.148 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.utils_1.0.200.v201201032002.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.utils 2 0
>   2013-09-26 11:34:32.148 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.utils 2 0 2013-09-26 11:34:32.148 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.ide_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-26 11:34:32.148 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.ui_3.8.2.v20130107-165834.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2013-09-26
>   11:34:32.148 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.team.ui_[3.4.100,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2
>   0 2013-09-26 11:34:32.148 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2013-09-26 11:34:32.148 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.ui.ide_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-26 11:34:32.148 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core_3.7.100.v20120521-2012.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.debug.core 2 0 2013-09-26
>   11:34:32.148 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi
>   2 0 2013-09-26 11:34:32.148 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui_1.0.500.v201205170400.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui 2 0 2013-09-26
>   11:34:32.148 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources_[3.2.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui 2 0 2013-09-26 11:34:32.148 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.ui.ide_[3.2.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-26 11:34:32.148 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.ui_1.1.500.v200911190730.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wst.common.ui 2 0 2013-09-26
>   11:34:32.148 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.ide_[3.4.0,4.0.0).

blah blah .

At the end of the log file is

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-09-26 11:34:32.476
>   !MESSAGE Application error
>   !STACK 1
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.eclipse.pde.build.Build, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.legacytestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplicationnonmain, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.nonuithreadtestapplication, org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.preview.
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

What do i need to do? I can't run the eclipse. Everytime i opened the error appeared. I tried changing the environment variables on window suggested through the internet but not working even use eclipse -clean also not successful

Comment: What do you mean by "software upload"? It might help to actually show the parts you skipped over.

Comment: sorry i mean update. I tried to update all the packages from the up to API 18. After that as far as I remembered, I tried to run the AVD  through eclipse to select the emulator. Instead of showing me the AVD screen, eclipse ask me to to an update (can't remember the message). Then I tried updated it. I restart my eclipse after updated, after that I received this error log when launching eclipse

Comment: If you started with the ADT bundle, you might have to redownload it.